# Meet issue with org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.simple.SimpleLoginModule create when cq5 login module

Tags: java, aem, jackrabbit, jcr, sling

I want to write login module for my CQ5 application so i apply [this API](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/1.5/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/security/simple/SimpleLoginModule.html)

I put this api to my servlet code but it doesn't work. Any one show me the right way ? Here is my implementation:

```
@SlingServlet(paths = { "/bin/app/signin" }, methods = { "POST" }, metatype = true)
public class SigninServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(SigninServlet.class);

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request,
            SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("{message : start}");
        Session session = JcrUtils.getSession(request);
        try {

            UserManager userManager = AccessControlUtil.getUserManager(session);
            //check if contain input username.
            Authorizable authorizable = userManager.getAuthorizable("admin");

                    //create credential from input username and password
            Credentials credential = new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray());

            Principal principal = authorizable.getPrincipal();

            Map<String, String> sharedState = new HashedMap();

            Map<String, String> options = new HashedMap();
            options.put(LoginModuleConfig.PARAM_ADMIN_ID, "admin");
            options.put(LoginModuleConfig.PARAM_PRINCIPAL_PROVIDER_CLASS, "org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.principal.DefaultPrincipalProvider");

            SimpleLoginModule sim = new SimpleLoginModule();

            Subject subject = new Subject();
            subject.getPrincipals().add(principal);
            subject.getPublicCredentials().add(credential);

            sim.initialize(subject, null, sharedState, options);
            sim.login();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println("{error message: " + e.getMessage() + "}");
            LOG.warn(e.getMessage());
        }

        out.flush();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the error.log. Please paste the errors here.

Comment: Are you running this as a standalone java code? or you are running it from an OSGi bundle?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but this is not how login modules work in CQ5. If your goal is to implement your own login mechanism, the docs at http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/core/deploying/custom-login-modules.html should help.